Pandas: multiindex group
I have the following data:
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

data = [['id',    'date',      'b_field',   'a_field'],
        ['XYX',   '01/01/2024',  100,        101],
        ['XYX',   '01/02/2024',  200,        201],
        ['ABC',   '01/01/2024',  300,        301],
        ['ABC',   '01/02/2024',  400,        401]]

id_sort=['ABC', 'XYZ']
field_sort=['a_field', 'b_field']
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[:1])


I would like to effectively transform this such that if I were to serialize this to a csv or json array it would look like this:

where:

the ID is grouped at the top (not repeated for each column)
sort by ID and then fields
DATE label on the same column row as the field

So far I've tried a few things. The closest I have come is the following:
df.set_index('date').reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([id_sort, field_sort]),axis=1).reset_index()

Of course, as you can see there are several issues:

no values
the 'date' label is at the top level, not 2nd
dates look like a tuple, not sure why


EDIT:
For #2, for shifting the date label down, it looks like I can do this (not sure if it's the best way):
df = df.rename(columns={'date': '', '':'date'})


Note that you have a typo in your data XYX/XYZ

Looks like you could pivot, swaplevel, and reindex with your custom index.
A better approach to move the "date" as top level would be to rename_axis with a tuple of ('date', '') before calling reset_index:
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

id_sort=['ABC', 'XYX']
field_sort=['a_field', 'b_field']

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([id_sort, field_sort])

out = (df.pivot(index='date', columns='id').swaplevel(axis=1)
         .reindex(idx, axis=1)
         .rename_axis([('date', '')]).reset_index()
      )

Output:
         date     ABC             XYX        
              a_field b_field a_field b_field
0  01/01/2024     301     300     101     100
1  01/02/2024     401     400     201     200


one note: for very large datasets, this produces PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance..  i thinking i should sort by the multiindex first?

@mike01010 indeed, you can first sort_,index,()

Here's one approach:
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

out = (
    df
    .set_index(['id', 'date'])
    .unstack(0)
    .swaplevel(axis=1)
    .sort_index(axis=1)
    .rename_axis(index=[('date', '')],
                 columns=(None, None))
    .reset_index()
)

Output
         date     ABC             XYX        
              a_field b_field a_field b_field
0  01/01/2024     301     300     101     100
1  01/02/2024     401     400     201     200

Explanation

First, correct input for columns inside pd.DataFrame. columns=data[:1] will lead to tuples like ('id',). I trust you want just the strings as headers: data[0].
Next, get ['id', 'date'] as index with df.set_index, and df.unstack 'id' (level 0).
Now, swap column levels with df.swaplevels, apply df.sort_index, and get rid of the column name ('id') with df.rename_axis.
Also, adding [('date', '')] here for renaming the index to end up with ('date','') rather than ('','date') after a final df.reset_index. (following the approach by @mozway in this.)


thank you. adding this to the end looks like it will handle the 'date' label: .reset_index().rename(columns={'date': '', '':'date'})
How efficient is this?  the dataset may be as much as a million rows i will do this on?

Updated with 'date' back as first column, chaining df.reset_index as the end.

Performance wise, there seems to be not that much between my solution and the one offered by @mozway. I get 3.05 (mine) vs. 3.25 (mozway) on a  df with shape (1000000, 4), individual id values. Suppose one potential benefit of mozway's approach is that it allows an easy custom sort, in case a simple sort_index won't do (but in this case it does :)).

yeah i tested and it actually fluctuates as far as performance between the 2 solutions.  between 0.01 - 0.03ms.   His solutions does address the sorting.
i can only mark one solution.  so much appreciated...

No worried, good luck with the project!

You have to use Pivot using Lambda:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

    data = [['id',    'date',      'b_field',   'a_field'],
            ['XYZ',   '01/01/2024',  100,        101],
            ['XYZ',   '01/02/2024',  200,        201],
            ['ABC',   '01/01/2024',  300,        301],
            ['ABC',   '01/02/2024',  400,        401]]
    
    id_sort = ['ABC', 'XYZ']
    field_sort = ['a_field', 'b_field']
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0], index=None)
    
    # Set 'id' as index
    df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
    
    # Sort the index according to id_sort
    df = df.loc[id_sort]
    
    # Reset index to make 'id' a column again
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    
    # Melt the DataFrame to reshape it
    df_melted = df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'date'],
                        value_vars=field_sort, var_name='field')
    df.index = df.index + 1
    # Pivot the melted DataFrame to get the desired format
    df_pivot = df_melted.pivot(
        index='date', columns=['id', 'field'], values='value').reset_index()
    
    # Flatten the MultiIndex columns
    df_pivot.columns = df_pivot.columns.map(
        lambda x: '_'.join(map(str, x)) if x[1] else x[0])
    
    print(df_pivot)


